# Handling UpperCase and LowerCase letters EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am using a TextWatcher so that when I start typing something in my edit text it appears all capital, but I need to add a functionality that when I press `ENTER`, then on typing everything should be in small letters. how do I do it?

Here is textwatcher

```
scene.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {            

            }
                @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                            int arg3) {             
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                  String s=arg0.toString();

              if(!s.equals(s.toUpperCase()))
              {
                 s=s.toUpperCase(); 
                 scene.setText(s);
                 scene.setSelection(scene.getText().length());

              }
            }
        });
```

And here is the code for handling the event of ENTER

```
scene.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    String s = scene.getText().toString();
                    s=s+'\n';
                    scene.setText(s);
                    scene.setSelection(scene.getText().length());
                        ib2(scene);

                      return true;
                    }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Comment: and what's your question?

Comment: Please read the question properly before commenting .

Comment: but i need to add a functionality that when i press ENTER, then on typing everything should be in small letters

Comment: actually I read it, and I was not able to find a single question mark.

Comment: so, do you want to switch between uppercase and lowercase every time you press Enter?

Comment: @Brontok no, problem is not solved yet.

Comment: @blackbelt yes i want to switch between lowercase and uppercase everytime i press enter

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need **toLowerCase**

```
String input = "Cricket!";
String upper = input.toUpperCase(); //stores "CRICKET!"
String lower = input.toLowerCase(); //stores "cricket!"
```

In your onKey method do like this

```
  String s = scene.getText().toString();
  s=s.toLowerCase();
  scene.setText(s);
```

Update your setOnKeyListener method like this

```
scene.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {


                      String s = scene.getText().toString();
                      s=s.toLowerCase();
                      scene.setText(s);
                      scene.setSelection(scene.getText().length());
                        ib2(scene);

                      return true;
                    }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Comment: No, it did not work either, i guess the textwatcher approach is not a good way to handle this problem

Comment: can you help me with some other approach, i have tried almost everything. i have tried to hook shift key, but could'nt find a way to do it properly

Comment: Or i was wondering, that once the enter key is pressed, can we disable the textwatcher?

Comment: I guess you don't need to add textwatcher , above code will solve the purpose.

Comment: but then how can i make the text all capital on the start of the activity? i am implementing the text watcher so that when the user starts writing the text, it must be in all caps

Comment: you can include android:inputType="textCapCharacters" in EditText in your layout